# Unable to increment last 2 digit of variable declared in file using script

Tags: shell, unix

I have the file given below:

```
elix554bx.xayybol.42> vi setup.REVISION
# Revision information
setenv RSTATE R24C01
setenv CREVISION X3
exit
```

My requirement is to read RSTATE from file and then increment last 2 digits of RSTATE in setup.REVISION file and overwrite into same file.
Can you please suggest how to do this?

Comment: Is the number always 01 or does the code need to handle 00..99?  What about if the last three characters are 199?  Does that become 200, 1100, or 100 or something else?  Come to that, what if the last three characters are C99?  Also, are you using real `vi` or is that `vim` in disguise?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `vim`, then you can use the sequence:

```
/RSTATE/
$<C-a>:x
```

The first line is followed by a return and searches for RSTATE.  The second line jumps to the end of the line and uses <kbd>Control-a</kbd> (shown as `<C-a>` above, and in the `vim` documentation) to increment the number.  Repeat as often as you want to increment the number.  The `:x` is also followed by a return and saves the file.

The only tricky bit is that the leading 0 on the number makes `vim` think the number is in octal, not decimal.  You can override that by using `:set nrformats=` followed by return to turn off octal and hex; the default value is `nrformats=octal,hex`.

You can learn an awful lot about `vim` from the book [Practical Vim: Edit Text at the Speed of Thought](http://pragprog.com/book/dnvim/practical-vim) by Drew Neil.  This information comes from Tip 10 in chapter 2.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an `awk` one-liner type solution:

```
awk '{
    if ( $0 ~ 'RSTATE' ) {
    match($0, "[0-9]+$" );
    sub( "[0-9]+$",
        sprintf( "%0"RLENGTH"d", substr($0, RSTART, RSTART+RLENGTH)+1 ),
        $0 );
    print; next;
    } else { print };
}' setup.REVISION > tmp$$
mv tmp$$ setup.REVISION
```

Returns:

```
setenv RSTATE R24C02
setenv CREVISION X3
exit
```

This will handle transitions from two to three to more digits appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote for you a class.

```
class Reader
{
    public string ReadRs(string fileWithPath)
    {
        string keyword = "RSTATE";
        string rs = "";
        if(File.Exists(fileWithPath))
        {
            StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(fileWithPath);
            try
            {
                string line = "";
                bool finded = false;
                while (reader != null && !finded)
                {
                    line = reader.ReadLine();
                    if (line.Contains(keyword))
                    {
                        finded = true;
                    }
                }
                int index = line.IndexOf(keyword);
                rs = line.Substring(index + keyword.Length +1, line.Length - 1 - (index + keyword.Length));
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
                //Error
            }
            finally
            {
                reader.Close();
            }

        }

        return rs;
    }
    public int GetLastTwoDigits(string rsState)
    {
        int digits = -1;
        try
        {
            int length = rsState.Length;
            //Get the last two digits of the rsstate                
            digits = Int32.Parse(rsState.Substring(length - 2, 2));
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            //Format Error
            digits = -1;
        }

        return digits;
    }
}
```

You can use this as exists

```
Reader reader = new Reader();
string rsstate = reader.ReadRs("C://test.txt");
int digits = reader.GetLastTwoDigits(rsstate);
```